# move bootstrap selector box form to align to left of the page

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I am using bootstrap cdn and I have the following form that creates a drop down box. Strangely the legend tag is correctly aligned to the left of the page, however the selector box is somewhat indented on the page towards the center. How can I move the selector box to align to the left of the page so its lined up with the legend tag?

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action="{{ url_for('db_selected') }}" name="Item_1" method="POST">
    <fieldset>
    <legend>Select a Database</legend>
    <div class="form-group">
    <label for="select" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Database:</label>
    <select id="DB" class="form-control" name="Item_4" style="width: 70%" >
        <option></option>
        {% for item in coll_name %}
            <option value="{{item}}">{{item}}</option>
        {% endfor %}
    </select>
    <br>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="col-sm-10 col-lg-offset-2">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
  </div>
</div>
</fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/trixta/7DETa/ check this for alternative solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have added a sample output of your code. So, please check the updated `DOM` also added some `css`.

```css
select#DB {
  display: inline-block;
}
.control-label{
  text-align: left;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="fluid-container">
    <form class="" action="{{ url_for('db_selected') }}" name="Item_1" method="POST">
        <fieldset>
        <legend>Select a Database</legend>    
        <div class="form-group">
        <label for="select" class="control-label">Database:</label>
        <select id="DB" class="form-control" name="Item_4" style="width: 70%" >
            <option></option>
            <option value="item">item</option>
            <option value="item">item</option>
            <option value="item">item</option>
        </select>
        <br>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
    </div>
    </fieldset>
    </form>
</div>
```

You can also check this [Fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/n4x3tL3q/1/) Hope it will help you.

Comment: Thank you very much. This definitely moves the selector box to the left. But one final thing. How do I get it so the label tag with the text "Database" and the selector box are not on different lines? Currently it shows these things on different lines. Would be good if this was all on the same line.

Comment: Thanks, Just add `display: inline-block;` to `label`. You can also check the updated answer.